# different blur behavior for button and select

Tags: javascript, jquery, blur

There is a different behavoir for "blur" event on buttons and select. 
1) klick in textarea > expand textare
2b) klick in select > DONT shrink textare  > thats correct!
or
2a) klick on button > shrink textarea   > how can i prevent that?

```
<table class="codeBlock">
<tr>
    <td>
        <button>Hallo</button>
        <select>
            <option>A</option>
            <option>B</option>
        </select>
        <textarea>Some text</textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="codeBlock">
    <td>
        <textarea>Some text</textarea>
        <select>
            <option>A</option>
            <option>B</option>
        </select>
        <button>Hallo</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

```
    $(document).on("blur", ".codeBlock", function () {
        $("textarea", this).height("40px");
    });

    $(document).on("focus", ".codeBlock", function () {
        $("textarea", this).height("80px");
    });
```

You can try it at ... [ysfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/klwemu/qfvVG/)

Comment: I don't think button has a blur event, it's not selectable.

Comment: events bubble, so when an element inside your table has focus, the focus event handler bound to the table is triggered. A button does'nt have a focus event, so when clicking it the other focusable elements loose focus, and the blur event is triggered.